# How do I solve Kera's MeanIoU Confusion matrix error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras-metrics

I am using Tensorflow 2.8.
When I try evaluating my pre-trained(pix2pix) image segmentation model using MeanIoU, I get the errors below:

```bash
Node: 'confusion_matrix/assert_non_negative_1/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert'
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  assertion failed: [`predictions` contains negative values.  ] [Condition x >= 0 did not hold element-wise:] [x (confusion_matrix/Cast:0) = ] [0 0 0...]
     [[{{node confusion_matrix/assert_non_negative_1/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]
     [[confusion_matrix/assert_less_1/Assert/AssertGuard/pivot_f/_31/_65]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  assertion failed: [`predictions` contains negative values.  ] [Condition x >= 0 did not hold element-wise:] [x (confusion_matrix/Cast:0) = ] [0 0 0...]
     [[{{node confusion_matrix/assert_non_negative_1/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_50298]
```

Here is my compilation code:

```py
myTransformer.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss = DiceLoss(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes=100)])
```

I have tried changing `num_classes` to many values eg:10,100,1000,10000, and it still doesn't work.
Do you have a fix for this?

Comment: _`predictions` contains negative values._ seems pretty clear as error...

Comment: Which solution do you suggest?

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62331792/tensorflow-invalid-argument-assertion-failed-predictions-contains-negative

Comment: I am using transfer learning. How do I control the learning rates of the pre-trained model?

Comment: afaik, transfer learning uses a pretrained model with additional layer that _you need to train_...